# Iterative divide and conquer

Tags: c, algorithm

This code, in every loop cycle creates twice smaller segment that it adds to number 0. Problem is that, if you split 50 you get 25 and 25 and if you split 51 you also get 25. This x and y should represent array index so they start from 0. If you know better  iterative algorithm (must not use recursion) I'll be glad to see it but I really wnat to solve this problem this way(unless it can't be done).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int a, b, x, r, y;
    printf("Enter N: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = 0;
    b = n - 1;
    x = a;
    y = b;
    r = b;
    printf(" %2d %2d\n", a, b);
    while(b > 1)
    {
        r /= 2;
        while(x < n - 1)
        {
            printf(" %2d ", x);
            y = x + r;          //if(something) y = x + r - 1;
            printf("%2d", y);   //else  y = x + r; 
            x = y + 1;
        }
        x = a;
        b = r;
        y = b;
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Enter N: 50
  0 49
  0 24 25 49
  0 12 13 25 26 38 39 51
  0  6  7 13 14 20 21 27 28 34 35 41 42 48
  0  3  4  7  8 11 12 15 16 19 20 23 24 27 28 31 32 35 36 39 40 43 44 47 48 51
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49

Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...
```

Comment: I don't understand the goal. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand what's going on either, or why the given output is wrong... the last iteration does give a list of numbers from 0 to 50.

Comment: Tell the problem in two words so other users will be able to answer your question.

Comment: I wnat to split number 49 to 0-24 and 25-49 then split 0-24 to 0-12 and 13 -24 and split everything untile it can't be split

Comment: Why is this tagged c++?

Comment: `(size + 1) / 2`  might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a breadth-first traversal problem and should be implemented with a **queue**. I do not think that there is a simple way to implement breadth-first recursion, so an iterative approach will have to do. The following is a rough algorithm:

1) Create two queues, `q` and `p`, containing your initial range `[a, b]`.

[image]

2) While `p` is not empty, dequeue an element from `p` and print it.

[image]

3) While `q` is not empty, dequeue an element `[i, j]` from `q` and enqueue two new ranges `[i, (i + j) / 2]` and `[(i + j) / 2 + 1, j]` into `p`.

[image]

4) Copy `p` to `q`.

[image]

5) If `q` has a size of `a + b + 1`, then you are done. Otherwise, go back to step 2.

Here is my implementation in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

struct Pair
{
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public Pair(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        int size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Queue<Pair> queue = new Queue<Pair>();
        queue.Enqueue(new Pair(0, size));

        bool lastRound = false;

        do
        {
            if (queue.Count == size + 1)
            {
                lastRound = true;
            }

            Queue<Pair> temporary = new Queue<Pair>(queue);

            while (temporary.Count > 0)
            {
                Pair pair = temporary.Dequeue();

                if (pair.b - pair.a == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", pair.a);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}-{1} ", pair.a, pair.b);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                Pair pair = queue.Dequeue();

                if (pair.b - pair.a == 0)
                {
                    temporary.Enqueue(new Pair(pair.a, pair.b));
                }
                else
                {
                    temporary.Enqueue(new Pair(pair.a, (pair.a + pair.b) / 2));
                    temporary.Enqueue(new Pair((pair.a + pair.b) / 2 + 1, pair.b));
                }
            }

            queue = temporary;
        } while (!lastRound);
    }
}
```

Here is its output:

```
Enter a number: 20
0-20
0-10 11-20
0-5 6-10 11-15 16-20
0-2 3-5 6-8 9-10 11-13 14-15 16-18 19-20
0-1 2 3-4 5 6-7 8 9 10 11-12 13 14 15 16-17 18 19 20
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Good answer, and as I suspected this takes extra memory since each round relies on stored results from a prior round.

Answer (score 2):

Do a google search for quicksort.  You will find many examples of code that use this technique.

Answer (score 0):

When you're splitting the number, you'll need to decide whether there is a remainder or not (depending on whether the number you are splitting is odd or even).

You will need to handle the two different scenarios differently. You will also have to decide where to put the extra number (on the first half or the second half).

Perhaps a possible modification is to have two r's to track the two halves.

Answer (score 0):

The root of problem is that a fixed jump size (r) cannot be calculated for each iteration. A constant
r for each iteration will work only when the starting number
is a power of two (try starting with 64 and you will see that it all works as you want). For any other number the 
jump size (r) may be either r or r+1 depending on whether
the prior iteration divided the current range being split into an even or odd number of elements. Consequently
the value of r may not be a constant throughout the entire iteration.

As soon as you see that the current iteration depends on results from a prior iteration the words "stack" or "recursion" pop up
as immediate solutions. This is because prior state information is needed to solve the problem.

There may be a purely iterative solution to your problem, but I think that it will either take some interesting
math or extra memory to maintain state information.